# \ characters adding where they shouldn't be

Tags: php, python, ssh, ubuntu-11.04

PHP:

```
$var = "Sum Random'z String"s with quotemarks"
$send = base64_encode($var)
```

Then it sends the base64 encoded string to server.

Server part (Python) tryes to decode the base64-encoded content and write it into file:

```
f = open("/root/data.yml","w")
f.write(base64.b64decode(sys.argv[1]))
f.close()
```

sys.argv[1] is $send

However, when i open data.yml in *nano* or *cat*, i get this:

```
Sum Random\'z String\"s with quotemarks
```

I dont want \ there.
Is there a way so the \ character will not appear there, when i open it in *nano* or *cat*? What shall i change?
**EDIT:**
$var is taken from textarea where there are no \

Comment: Show us the base64 encoded string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to escape both the single and double quote. You only need to escape what you're quoting the string with (i.e. `"`)

```
$var = "Sum Random'z String\"s with quotemarks";
```

This may not be your only problem. But it is part of the problem.

#### UPDATE

Per your update of `$var` being set with data from a form textarea, you need to look at [stripslashes()](http://php.net/stripslashes)

Comment: But that does not explain the `\"` in the output. Magic Quotes, maybe?

Comment: `$var` being set from a textarea changes everything. See update.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here i think is that your escaping a charactor that does not need to be escaped, single qoutres inside double qoutes do not need to be escaped, and visa-versa.

example:

```
OK; " ' "
OK; ' " '
NO; ' ' '
OK; ' \' '
NO; " " "
OK; " \" "
```

Try doing the following:

```
$var = 'Sum Random\'z String"s with quotemarks';
$send = base64_encode($var);
```

**Edit**: you never said anything about it coming from a textarea, try running `stripslashes` on the value before you encode it.

Answer (score 0):

the php looks fine to me. i bet there is some security mechanism that's escaping dangerous characters behind you back.

you can unescape them yourself with the equivalent of stripslashes in python.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like [magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc) are enabled in PHP.

If you have access you can edit the php.ini or try this before sending the data: `ini_set('magic_quotes_runtime', 0);`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:-

```
f = open("/root/data.yml","w")
x = base64.b64decode(sys.argv[1])
x.replace("\"", "")
f.write(x)
f.close()
```

Hope it helps.